# Compiling & Accessing Cython Functions from Python

Tags: python, numpy, gcc, cython, distutils

I have been developing a cython function inside an Ipython notebook using the cell magic `%%cython` to compile my code. This works successfully, and I am able to call the compiled function in cells without the cython magic present.

I now wish to be able to compile my cython function to a (library, object?) such that I am able to import it into pure python scripts, via `import <foo>`.

My problem is that I am at a loss in terms of how to use `distutils` properly to specify the correct setup options. For example, my `%%cython` cell magic is:

`%%cython -lgsl -L/usr/lib64/atlas -ltatlas -lm`

And I am not sure how to pass these arguments to gcc from distutils.

I also pass extra arguments (flags?), at the beginning of the cython maigic cell as follows:

```
import Cython.Compiler.Options as CO
CO.extra_compile_args = ["-f",'-O3',"-ffast-math","openmp","march=native"]
CO.extra_link_args = ["-fopenmp"]
```

I realise some of these may be unnecessary but the code is compiling and running correctly *inside the notebook*.

Since my function also calls numpy and scipy, I am aware I need to link these libraries, too.

I have attempted to compile the function via gcc by first running (from the command line):

```
cython <my_func>.pyx --embed
```

And then:

```
gcc -O3 -fopenmp -ffast-math <my_func>.c -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I<numpy_include> -L<numpy-location> -L/usr/lib64/atlas -lgsl -ltatlas -lm -lpython2.7 -o <my_func>.so
```

Which successfully produces a `<my_func>.so`, but I am then unable to access anything inside it from python.

Importing `<my_func>.so`as a C-library with Ctypes does not work either as Ctypes is unable to find my function in the shared object.

I realise constructing a `setup.py` script using `distutils` is probably the "correct" way to go about this, but I have been unable to find any resources explaining how to link and include numpy, scipy and some C-libraries (GSL) while passing additional compile flags to gcc.

What is the best way to compile and call this cython function from outside a notebook?

Comment: The arguments you're adding are just libraries and library directories, hence the duplicate is what you want to do.

Comment: This is also all covered in detail in the documentation: http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/reference/compilation.html#compiling-with-distutils

Comment: Thank you, David - this is what I have been looking for.